# Adding new aggregate function in Presto fails

Tags: java, presto

I am trying to build custom aggregate functions for presto. I have created a FAT Jar and deployed the jar into the plugin directory. When I restart presto, it is always giving me this error :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.installPlugin(PluginManager.java:183)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:175)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:158)
```

Unfortunately, I do not see any verbose error message which will give me a clue on what is actually missing here. I used presto-ml plugin as an example and implemented getFunctions() in plugin implementation. Is there a way to figure out what is missing?
I did check the source code of PLuginManager.java. I am just looking for a way to debug this in a better way.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace? What is presto version? Why are building a "FAT Jar"? You should be using `<packaging>presto-plugin</packaging>` and your artifact should be a zip file (to be unzipped in the `plugins/yourplugin` folder).

Comment: The stack trace is exactly that I pasted above. The error was showing up due to a version mismatch. The installed presto-server had a different version. Once I fixed that, it worked.